I'm trying to add animation to the buttons that were not tapped
Is a game selection with 3 different options per round. I added an animation to the button selected. But I'm trying to add an animation for the buttons that are not selected. I'm new to Swift and SwiftUI, I've been stuck in this problem that sounds easy to fix but I'm blocked at this point.
ForEach(0..<3) { number in
                    
        Button{
            flagWasTapped = true // State property to track the btn tapped
            flagTapped(number) // func to validate answer
            animation360 += 360
            fadeOut = 1
        }
        
        label: {
            ImageFlag(img: ImageResource(name: countries[number],  bundle: .main)).rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animation360), axis: (x: 0, y: 1, z: 0)).opacity(flagWasTapped ? fadeOut:0.50)
        }
    }
}

I've tried if statements, creating my modifier to use it inside a ternary operator but I don't know how to target those buttons that are not being selected

What animations are you trying to add? Can you show a [mcve] of how your current does not work?

Look into a custom button style you can isolate all the code and have full control.
